# Prevent a layer rotation on map rotate in mapbox-gl

Tags: mapbox-gl

Is there anyway to disable layer rotation on map ratation ?
I am using a symbol layer with arrow image icon and I don't want them ro ratate with map and stay fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set "icon-rotation-alignment" to "map" (it's "auto" by default).

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-rotation-alignment:

> "map": When symbol-placement is set to point, aligns icons east-west.
> When symbol-placement is set to line or line-center, aligns icon
> x-axes with the line.